# Как остановить интервал при превышении 1080px

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который увеличивает высоту элемента каждую одну секунду.
Каким образом сделать так, чтобы при превышении высоты элемента в 1080px скрипт переставал работать.
Мой скрипт не останавливает цикл, когда высота элемента достигает 1080px.
Помогите понять, что я сделал не так.

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#block');

let go = setInterval(function() {

  a.style.height = a.offsetHeight * 2 + 'px';

  if (a.style.height >= 1080) {
    clearInterval(go);
  }

}, 1000);
```

```css
#block {
  background: orange;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  Как дела?
</div>
```

Comment: В clearInterval нужно передавать не функцию, а идентификатор нужного интервала, а чтобы идентификатор нужного интервала откуда-то взять, нужно его сперва куда-то сохранить: `var идентификатор = setInterval(...`

Comment: Спасибо, я сделал как вы и сказали, но все равно цикл не останавливается(

Comment: Проблема в условии. Выведите в консоле `a.style.height`. И лучше это сделать так: `if(a.style.height >= 1080)`

Comment: Изменил условие, не помогло (

Comment: parseInt(a.style.height)

Comment: Что parseInt(a.style.height) это нужно записать в условие?

Comment: Можно написать полный код с parseInt(a.style.height). Я вставил это в условие, не помогает(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let a = document.querySelector('#block');

let go = setInterval(function() {
  const newHeight = a.offsetHeight * 2;
  a.style.height = newHeight + 'px';

  if (newHeight >= 270) {
    console.log('stop');
    clearInterval(go);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#block {
  background: orange;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  Как дела?
</div>
```

Comment: Ух ты, шикарно =)

Comment: Вы обошлись без parseInt(), разве так можно было?

Comment: @Хмельни́цький "можно"? Кто мне может это запретить?

Comment: Просто программисты вверху сказали, что нужно строго писать parseInt()

Comment: @Хмельни́цький Разберитесь в том, что делает Ваш и мой код, а не полагайтесь на программистов вверху.

Comment: Cпасибо за совет =)